# Image map wrongly in release build for React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, image

I'm using `require(./image/xx.png)` to pass in the `<Image>` source. It appears to happen on Android **release build** only.

The images are showing up but they are wrongly map all over the screen [refer:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZBNu.jpg)]. It occurs whenever user installed new update over the old version.

If user uninstall and reinstall, then the app appears fine. But I couldn't force user to uninstall and reinstall each time new update is released to store.

`"react-native": "0.66.1",`

**Example usage:**

```
const IMG_LOGO = require('../../../assets/image/logo.png')

<Image source={IMG_LOGO} style={styles.imgLogo} resizeMode='contain'/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by downgrading fresco version from `2.6.0` to `2.5.0`

`implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.5.0'`

Solution from
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32671