# Image map wrongly in android update of React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, image, mapping, android-update-app

I experience the same issue as stated here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70705743/image-map-wrongly-in-release-build-for-react-native-app)

Whenever I update to a new version on android with any image added to the source code and imported via require... I will see the icons and images mapped to the wrong places. On fresh install everything works fine and on iOS there is no problem at all.

**With the exception that it happens on any build when updating on android.**
The fix that was described over in the other question did not help unfortunately. Neither the one in the link over in github.

So I tried already adding:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.5.0'
```

which did not help. (Also maybe obviously because it is animated gif?)
And I tried adding:

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    force "com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.5.0"
}
```

}

Each time I build the whole bundle in that version and try the update. Each time the results will slightly differ and some other image or icon will get replaced in the wrong place.

Actually it seems weird to me as the dependency tree shows 2.5.0 everywhere. So why would there be the need for this?

I am running  `"react": "18.1.0", "react-native": "0.70.1",`

Comment: did you managed to find the solution for this?

Comment: hey, I did not find a real solution - I only found that it only happens to me when I create a debug build in android. Thus I could basically ignore it.